# Finding nth object in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, parsing, csv

I was given a large CSV file with about 100 or so different values. I'm trying to get a script in JavaScript to find every value of a column. The CSV is split by new lines and looks something like this:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
Value1_1,Value1_2,Value1_3,Value1_4
Value2_1,Value2_2,Value2_3,Value2_4
Value3_1,Value3_2,Value3_3,Value3_4
```

What I'm looking to do is create an array of that would have something like;

```
[Value1_3, Value2_3, Value3_3]
```

So what I started doing was this to split the csv file into an array of arrays like so

```
    var new_split = csv_file.split('\n')
    var url_split = [];
    for(i = 0; i < new_split.length; i++) {
         new_split[i].split(',')
    };
```

With this I can find a "row" by using new_split[i], however I want to find every 3rd object in every row and have that output to an array. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: `values = csv.split('\n').map(row => row.split(',')[2])`

Comment: You could also try to use a csv parser like [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/)